# active directory simple bind always anonymous (event 1219)

Tags: active-directory, ldap, authentication

I am getting event 1219: "Active Directory could not initialize simple bind authentication. Therefore, simple bind authentication against this LDAP interface will result in binding as an unauthenticated user" on each ADDS start.

It's a problem because some of our services require simple bind.
Also there are some warnings:

Event 2886: "The following client performed a SASL (Negotiate/Kerberos/NTLM/Digest) LDAP bind without requesting signing ..." right after 1219,

and event 1539: "Active Directory Domain Services could not disable the software-based disk write cache on the following hard disk. Hard disk: %1 Data might be lost during system failures.", before 1219.

Any ideas?

Can it be not working for some policy reasons?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941849%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 describes similar situation in section verify,

can i do something to allow simple bind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution found:

```
regedit HKLM/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/SecurityProviders/SecurityProviders - add pwdssp.dll
```